# centering a row of divs in a container

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a little problem to center my divs in a container. I tried  every thing I could find but the problem still exists.
The goal is to place the green boxes in the middle of the yellow one. It should be responsive. The main issue is the floating box which isn't centering.

I also don't get why the yellow space still exist in the small view. The green box should be over the whole place (the example below looks weird).

```css
body,html{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;

}

#hans{
  background:red;
  width:50rem;
  height:28%;
  display:table;


}

.test-center{
  height:30rem;
  width:90vw;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: yellow;
}


.content-block{
  background: green;
  width:45rem;
  height:90%;
  margin-left:1%;
  5margin-top: 8rem;
  display: inline-block;
  5padding-top:2rem;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--TzITT-->
    <title>Test right site</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container" id="hans">
    <div class= "test-center">
    <div class = "content-block">
      <p>fwfwf</p>
    </div>
    <div class = "content-block">
      <p>fwfwf</p>
    </div>
    <div class = "content-block">
      <p>fwfwf</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>



<div class = "footer">
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

[image: Klick Me for picture !!! Thx]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body,html{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;

}

#hans{
  background:red;
  width:50rem;
  height:28%;
  display:table;


}

.test-center{
  height:30rem;
  width:90vw;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: yellow;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}


.content-block{
  flex:1;
  background: green;
  height:90%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin:1%;
}

@media screen and (max-width:728px){
  .test-center {
    flex-direction:column;
  }
  
  .content-block{
    width:100%;

  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--TzITT-->
    <title>Test right site</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container" id="hans">
    <div class= "test-center">
    <div class = "content-block">
      <p>fwfwf</p>
    </div>
    <div class = "content-block">
      <p>fwfwf</p>
    </div>
    <div class = "content-block">
      <p>fwfwf</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>



<div class = "footer">
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi thx for ur fast feedback. If i lower the window size the green boxes also  gets smaler. I need to rearrange them under each other like it did before.

Comment: Thx man u helped me alot.
So the @media tag do alle the resize work?